# partitioning Windows 8 drive

Tags: partitioning

I have 3 partitions - Sys reserve, C, and D. When I try to create another partition it creates a logical drive not a primary drive and doesn't ask which one I want.

I need a primary with Fat32 format. How do I get it. I haven't had this issue with W7.

thx

Comment: How are yo trying to create the new partition? Disk Manager?  What kind of disk is it (dynamic, basic, gpt, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`diskpart`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415) from the command prompt.

Here's some basic instruction, you may want to read up on using Diskpart before you start, as this may not be the exact procedure you want to use (depending on what you want in the end).

1. Right-click the Command Prompt shortcut and click Run as administrator 
   (Start > All Programs > Accessories > Command Prompt).
2. Type DISKPART at the Prompt and press Enter.
3. Type LIST DISK at the Diskpart prompt and press Enter

   - Note the disk number for your new Unallocated space (Disk 0=1st hard disk, Disk 1=2nd, etc.).
4. Type SELECT DISK X (where x is the number you just noted)
5. Type CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY

   - All the Unallocated space will be used for the new Primary.
6. Type EXIT to exit Diskpart.
7. Type EXIT to exit Command Prompt.